# Codename One: Rename project

Tags: codenameone

I tried to rename my project to other one by Refactor\Rename, but I got errors after renaming processing finished and when I run project

[image]

[image]

Can you help me, please ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Post the errors, not links to screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use refactor/rename. There are many dependencies in the project creation especially with the main package name that can't be changed once you publish your app.

Create a new project with the correct packages/names and copy the sources manually to that project.